# Operator Overloading- concatenating two strings

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

In the following code, I am getting the error that *One of the parameters of a binary operator must be the containing type*
Whats wrong with the code?

```
public class Nest
{
    public string a = "Test";
    public string b = "Code";
}

class OperatorOverload
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Nest n = new Nest();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter first string");
        n.a = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter second string");
        n.b = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(n.a + n.b);

    }
    public static string operator + (string a, string b)
    {
        a = string.Concat(b);
        a = string.Concat(a);
        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you doing operator overloading because you can or because you have to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if if was me I'd override `ToString()` on Nest, to return `String.Concat(a,b)`.

Saves a lot of bogging about , when you add a c property to it.

Comment: Well that was a surprise! Welcome to the avoid operator overloading unless you have to club.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s53ehcz3.aspx)

*Use the operator keyword to overload a built-in operator or to provide a user-defined conversion in `a class` or `struct` declaration.* 
what are you doing it's wrong you should define it in  class like in msdn  example documentation